# Does tensoring with a module preserve this injection even if the module is not flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Suppose $R$ is a domain and let $Q$ be its field of fractions. Then $ 0 \to R \to Q $ is exact. Now suppose that $M$ is a torsion free $R$ module.

> Is it necessary that $ 0 \to M \to Q \otimes M $ is exact ?

This is true when $R$ is a PID. But I am not sure whether assuming that it is a domain suffices. If it is not please give a counter example. Thanks

Comment: Is $M$ an $R$-module ?

Comment: Anyway try to see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27150/example-of-modules-that-are-projective-but-not-free-torsion-free-but-not-free/27210#27210

Comment: @WLOG Yes, $M$ is an $R$ module. Thanks for pointing it out, I did not indicate that earlier and have now edited the question. I looked at the link but sorry I am unable to see how that would answer my question. I am not asking whether torsion free implies flat or not for general domains which are not PIDs, just asking whether injection is preserved in this one particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $R$ being an integral domain suffices. See Corollary 4.27 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works:
It's easy to see that both $Q(R) \otimes_{R}(-)$ and $(R-0)^{-1}(-)$ are two functors that works as left-adjoint to the forgetful functor from $Q(R)$ modules to $R$ modules.
This immediately tells you that the two functors are isomorphic. So this tells you that $Q(R) \otimes_{R}(M)$ and $(R-0)^{-1}(M)$ are naturally isomorphic.
Now you have by construction that $\frac{m}{1}=0$ in $(R-0)^{-1}M$ iff there is $a \neq 0$ in R such that $am=0$. That is, iff m is a torsion element.
So for torsion free elements, your map is injective.
Hope it helps and hope it works