# Is a finitely generated torsion-free module over a UFD necessarily free?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is a finitely generated torsion-free module over a unique factorization domain necessarily free ?

Answer (score 10):

No. Consider for example the polynomial ring over a field in two variables $R=K[x,y]$. $R$ is a UFD. Now consider the ideal $I=(x,y)$ generated by $x$ and $y$. It is easy to show that $I$ is not a free $R$-module, but it certainly is finitely generated and torsion-free.

Comment: So simple ! thx

Answer (score 3):

No. What we need is that the ring is a principal ideal ring, not just a UFD. A counter example has been just given above. Another generalization of a PID is a Dedekind ring. However, a finitely generated torsion-free module over a Dedekind ring is only projective, but not necessarily free (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27150/example-of-modules-that-are-projective-but-not-free-torsion-free-but-not-free).)

Comment: Answer about Dedekind rings interesting. Thx