# How to show $\mathbf{Q} $ is not free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

We know that torsion-free plus finitely generated $\rightarrow$ free and that $\mathbf{Q}$ is torsion-free is easy.

> But how to show $\mathbf{Q}$ is not finitely generated and not free?

Comment: we know torsion free plus finitely generated → free. But this does not mean that we know torsion free plus not finitely generated → not free.

Comment: "torsion free plus finitely generated $\rightarrow$ free" holds for modules over a PID like $\mathbb Z$, but not in general. For a simple (counter)example look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794285/is-a-finitely-generated-torsion-free-module-over-a-ufd-necessarily-free).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show any finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbf Q$ is cyclic. Since $\mathbf Q$ is not cyclic, it cannot be finitely generated.

$(1)$ [It cannot be free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074740/how-to-show-mathbfq-is-not-free/1074741#comment2186256_1074741): it is not cyclic, so any putative basis has at least two elements. But if $x,y$ are elements of the basis, we know $\mathbf Z^2\simeq \langle x,y\rangle=\langle x'\rangle\simeq\bf Z$ which is impossible. So no basis exists.

$(2)$ It cannot be free: if it were, say $\mathbf Q\simeq\mathbf Z^{(I)}$, then $\mathbf Q\simeq\mathbf Q\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Q\simeq \mathbf Q\otimes_{\mathbf Z}\mathbf Z^{(I)}\simeq \mathbf Q^{(I)}$. This forces $|I|=1$, which is absurd.

Comment: But it could be free and non-finitely generated! :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I was addressing "But how to show Q is not finitely generated?". I will address freedom in a minute. =)

Comment: You can use the fact that all f.g. subgroups are cyclic. It the thing were free, it woud have a basis. That basis cannot have two elements because the subgroup generated by two lements is cyclic and $\mathbb Z^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: can you explain why any finitely generated subgroup of Q is cyclic? for example, if A = <1/2,1/4>, and cyclic, what is the generator of A?

Comment: @annimal $1/4+1/4=1/2$. If $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ is a finite set of generatos, let $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ be the set of all primes in the denominators. Then $x=1/(p_1\ldots p_r)$ is a generator.

Comment: what do you mean by all primes?what if A = <1/2,5/6>, what should be the generator?

Comment: The primes in the denominator are $2$ fro $1/2$ and $2,3$ from $5/6$. So $1/6$ is a generator: $1/2=3\cdot 1/6$ and $5/6=5\cdot 1/6$.

Answer (score 11):

*For the non-free part*:

Take any two nonzero elements $x, y ∈ ℚ$ and show they satisfy $λx + μy = 0$ for some nonzero $λ, μ ∈ ℤ$, hence any two elements are linearly dependent. Thus, since $ℚ$ is not cyclic, it cannot have a basis.

*For the non-finitely-generated part*:

If $ℚ$ was finitely generated then without loss of generality (by finding the common denominator), there were a denominator $s ∈ ℤ$ and numerators $r_1, …, r_n ∈ ℤ$ such that
$$ℚ = ℤ\frac{r_1}{s} + \cdots + ℤ\frac{r_n}{s} = (ℤr_1 + \cdots+ ℤr_n)\frac{1}{s} = ℤ\frac{r}{s}$$
for $r = \gcd (r_1, …, r_n)$. Thus, since $ℚ$ isn’t cyclic, it isn’t finitely generated.

Answer (score 5):

If an abelian group $G\ne\{0\}$ is free, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ (direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$), for some set non empty set $X$.

Then $\mathbb{Z}$ is an epimorphic image of $G$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not divisible, $G$ can't be divisible. But $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible.

---

The group $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated: if $a_1/b_1, a_2/b_2,\dots,a_n/b_n$ are elements in $\mathbb{Q}$, then we can assume $b_1=b_2=\dots=b_n=b$ (the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are integers, of course); then
$$
\frac{1}{2b}=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\frac{a_i}{b} \qquad(c_1,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb{Z})
$$
implies $\frac{1}{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$, which is false; so the set $\{a_1/b,\dots,a_n/b\}$ doesn't generate $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more fundamental approach to showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated, based on a general method.

Here's the general method. In a group $G$ with a finite generating set $\{g_1,…,g_K\}$, for any increasing sequence of subgroups $H_1 \subset H_2 \subset \cdots$ whose union $\cup_i H_i$ equals $G$, for sufficiently large $i$ the subgroup $H_i$ equals $G$, because each $g_k$ is contained in some $H_{i_k}$ and so the whole generating set $\{g_1,…,g_K\}$ is contained in $H_I$ where $I = \text{max}\{i_k\}$.

Here's the application to $\mathbb{Q}$. Take $H_i$ to be the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by $\frac{1}{n_i}$ where $n_i$ is the product of the $i^{\text{th}}$ powers of the first $i$ prime numbers. Since $n_i$ divides $n_{i+1}$, $H_i$ is a subgroup of $H_{i+1}$, so the sequence is increasing $H_1 \subset H_2 \subset \cdots$. Since each integer divides some $n_i$, the union $\cup_i H_i$ equals $\mathbb{Q}$.